# How to create a python dataframe containing the mean of some rows of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame containing some values:

```
                        id  pair      value  subdir
taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  6_13  -0.398716    run1 
taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  6_13  -0.397820    run2 
taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  6_13  -0.397310    run3 
taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  6_13  -0.390520    run4 
taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  6_13  -0.377390    run5 
taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  8_11  -0.393604    run1
taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  8_11  -0.392899    run2
taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  8_11  -0.392473    run3
taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  8_11  -0.389959    run4
taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  8_11  -0.387946    run5
```

what I would like to do is to isolate the rows that have the same `index`, `id`, and `pair`, compute the mean over the `value` column, and put it all in a new dataframe. Because I have now effectively averaged over all the possible values of `subdir`, that column should also be removed. So the output should look something like this

```
                        id  pair      value
taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  6_13  -0.392351
taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  8_11  -0.391376
```

How should I do it in pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use syntactic sugar - [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `Series` and indices and [aggregate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation) `mean`:

```
df = df['value'].groupby([df.index, df['id'], df['pair']]).mean().reset_index(level=[1,2])
print (df)
                        id  pair     value
taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  6_13 -0.392351
taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  8_11 -0.391376
```

Classic solution - first [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from indices and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by columns names and [aggregate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation) `mean`:

```
df = df.reset_index().groupby(['index','id','pair'])['value'].mean().reset_index(level=[1,2])
print (df)
                        id  pair     value
index                                     
taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  6_13 -0.392351
taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  8_11 -0.391376
```

Detail:

```
print (df.reset_index())
                index      id  pair     value subdir
0  taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  6_13 -0.398716   run1
1  taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  6_13 -0.397820   run2
2  taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  6_13 -0.397310   run3
3  taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  6_13 -0.390520   run4
4  taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  6_13 -0.377390   run5
5  taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  8_11 -0.393604   run1
6  taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  8_11 -0.392899   run2
7  taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  8_11 -0.392473   run3
8  taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  8_11 -0.389959   run4
9  taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  8_11 -0.387946   run5
```

After aggregate `mean` get `MultiIndex` with `3 levels`:

```
print (df.reset_index().groupby(['index','id','pair'])['value'].mean())
index               id      pair
taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  6_13   -0.392351
                            8_11   -0.391376
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

So is necessesary [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for convert second ant third level to columns:

```
print (df.reset_index()
        .groupby(['index','id','pair'])['value']
        .mean()
        .reset_index(level=[1,2]))
                        id  pair     value
index                                     
taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  6_13 -0.392351
taylor_1e3c_1s_56C  taylor  8_11 -0.391376
```

Comment: Thanks much! I figured out most of it by looking the different concepts up, but why do I need to reset the index? And what does it mean to resect it at level 1,2?

Comment: I edit answer, thank you for comment. If something unclear, give me know.